# warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't know why I am getting below error

" warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]"

I have .h and .cpp file

in .h file, I have declare variable name

```
 class file
 {
   private:
     string* arr;
   public:
     void list();
 }
```

in .cpp file

```
void file::list()
{
  arr = new string[2]{"1", "2"}; 
}
```

Comment: Can you show your makefile? And also compiler version details.

Comment: @Harry, this is how my file looks like.

Comment: How you're compiling the program? Can you show that command?

Comment: g++ .cpp -o .exe

Comment: Please add the result of running `g++ --version` to the question.

Comment: Add in a `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++17` depending on how recent a standard you want to use and can use.

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4

Comment: Add that to the question please, not as a comment. Also, I suggest upgrading your gcc version. 4.8.4 is quite old now. Also, same for your OS, ubuntu 14 LTS expired last year.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why I am getting below error
>
> ```
> warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
> ```

You are getting the warning because you have used an initialiser list in context where it isn't allowed until C++11, and you are not using C++11 or later. As such, the program is ill-formed and the compiler is required to show you a message.

Comment: eerorika, if I use like this arr[0] = "1" then it's works. Is there way to fix this in older version?

Comment: @Newbie Rewrite it to use that code which works. Or use a later langauge version.